# Sorting step in Decision and Regression Trees

Tags: machine-learning, cart, algorithms

Several papers and implementations require the tree building algoirithms specifically the split finding to have values of individual features in sorted order. For example, the XGBoost manuscript says the following on page 5: "The most time consuming part of tree learning is to get the data into sorted order. In order to reduce the cost of sorting, we propose to store the data in in-memory units, which we called block ..." However, I am having trouble understanding why the feature values has to be in sorted order for efficiency. Let's say we have we have n different values for a given feature, e.g. $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n$ and we only have continuous feature values.

Most implementations of the CART algorithm will first sort the feature values and then use the average of each two features to test the thresholds. However, what I am proposing and don't understand how it's less efficient is why we can't just use the following implementation where we just loop over each feature value and then split the dataset up to test the impurity measure (or gain value) of each split. I use python for simplicity:

```
def get_best_split(self, X, Y):
    ''' function to find the best split '''

    # dictionary to store the best split
    imp_dec, feat_ind, thresh = -1, -1, -1

    # loop over all the features
    for feature_index in range(X.shape[1]):
        feature_values = X[:, feature_index]
        # loop over all the feature values present in the data
        for threshold in feature_values:
            # get current split and split array into two parts
            left_bool = X[:, feature_index] <= threshold
            Y_left = Y[left_bool]
            Y_right = Y[~left_bool]
            # check if childs are greater than min_samples_leaf
            if len(Y_left)>=1 and len(Y_right)>=1:
                # compute information gain (impurity decrease)
                N_p, N_L, N_R = len(Y), len(Y_left), len(Y_right)
                impurity_decrease = np.var(Y)-N_L/N_p*np.var(Y_left)-N_R/N_p*np.var(Y_right))
                if impurity_decrease > imp_dec:
                    imp_dec = impurity_decrease
                    feat_ind = feature_index
                    thresh = threshold
    return (imp_dec, feat_ind, thresh)
```

Most implementations however would sort the feature_values array and either use those or the boundary between those (average of the two feature values in order). I am wondering how this would be more efficient for the feature values in the algorithm to be in sorted order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to look at the situation where most of the values are distinct; the analysis is similar for discrete data but the differences are smaller.

If the values are sorted, you can compute the residual sums of squares for a new split in constant time, because all that happens at each step is that one value gets moved from the right to the left branch.  The total time is dominated by the $O(n\log n)$ for the sort.

With your implementation, you avoid the sort but you take time proportional to $n$ to recompute the loss function at each step, for a total of $\Theta(n^2)$

Here's an example function in R, finding the best cutpoint for predicting `y` from `x`.  This won't actually be fast, but if it were in something like C it would be, and you can see that everything other than the `sort` outside the loop is linear time at worst and the loop is constant-time for each iteration.

If the $x$s aren't all distinct you need to loop over the unique values, so the code is a bit more complicated but not much more.

````
## assume all x distinct
cutpoint<-function(x,y){
 i<-order(x)
 xsort<-x[i]
 ysort<-y[i]
 left_sum<-0
 left_sumsq<-0
 right_sum<-sum(y)
 right_sumsq<-sum(y*y)
 n_left<-0
 n<-n_right<-length(y)
 
 best_rss<- Inf
 best_cut<- NA
 
 for(i in 1:n){
    left_sum<-left_sum+y[i]
    left_sumsq<-left_sumsq+ysort[i]*ysort[i]
    right_sum<-right_sum-ysort[i]
    right_sumsq<-right_sumsq-ysort[i]*ysort[i]
    n_left<-n_left+1
    n_right<-n_right-1
    if (n_right>0 && n_left>0){
        rss<- (right_sumsq-right_sum^2/n_right)+(left_sumsq-left_sum^2/n_left)
    }
    if (rss<best_rss){
        best_rss<-rss
        best_cut<-xsort[i]
    }
    
 }      
    
list(best_cut, best_rss)    
}
```
````

Comment: Hello Thomas, 

Intuitively, I understand what you are saying but am having trouble recognizing which part of the code would make it faster. So let's say I call a sorted function before the second for loop:
"feature_values = np.sort(X[:, feature_index])"
what individual part would allow it to only move one item from left to right or would I have to change the way I am getting the current split:
"left_bool = X[:, feature_index] <= threshold"

Comment: You'd need to change how you're getting the current split, and how you're calculating the squared errors.  If you maintain `left_sum_x` and `right_sum_x` and `left_sum_xsquared` and `right_sum_xsquared` you can subtract the current $x$ and $x^2$ from the right sums and add them to the left sums, then compute the loss function difference from those sums. It's no longer a vectorised calculation and you don't really use `left_bool` at all.

Comment: Hello Thomas, 

Would you be able to clarify the loss function you are using in your R code? I have python background and am struggling to understand how it is equal to the sum of squared residuals loss. It seems like you are taking each element of the label y and squaring it. 

Thanks,

Comment: It's the sum of squared residuals.  $\mathrm{var}[Y]=E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$, and multiplying this by the sample size gives the residual sum of squares.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for the help. This makes more sense and I will post a python implementation as an answer to this post. One last question. When people use the term "impurity" as in the "min_impurity_decrease" in scikit-learn for example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html 

Are they referring to the variance or the sum of squared residuals loss function?

Thanks

Comment: Impurity usually refers to categorical outcomes, where it's the Gini impurity, the probability that two randomly chosen observations will be in different classes.

Comment: Hello Thomas, The impurity is defined in the scikit learn DecisionTreeRegressor class so I'm thinking that would just mean the variance.  What do you think: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html

Comment: That says it uses mean squared error, so yes.

Comment: Hello Thomas, Thanks. I posted another answer for the python implementation. Let me know what you think and about the unique values. I believe the duplicated features would be left in because this would affect the variance calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my previous code was that the comparison operation and the variance calculation from numpy was going through each element of the array to test whether it was less than the threshold and calculate the variance. The call to numpy would still have to iterate over every value in that particular feature. Thus, the time complexity would be $O(vn^2)$ with $v$ as number of features and $n$ as number of samples. If we implement it without these functions and increment the sums in the for loop with the formula for variance: $var(Y) = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2}{N}  + \left( \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i}{N}\right)^2 $ then the time complexity would be better: $O(vnlog(n)+vn)=O(vnlog(n))$ because we are not calling numpy in the iteration for each sample. The corrected python function would be the following:

```
def get_best_split(self, X, Y):
    """ function to find the best split """

    best_imp, best_feat, best_thresh = float('inf'), -1, -1
    for feature_index in range(X.shape[1]):
        indices = np.argsort(X[:, feature_index])
        X_sort, Y_sort = X[indices], Y[indices]
        left_sum_sq, left_sum = 0, 0
        right_sum_sq, right_sum = np.sum(Y_sort*Y_sort), np.sum(Y_sort)
        N_L = 0
        N = N_R = len(Y_sort)

        for i in range(N-1):
            left_sumsq, left_sum = left_sumsq+y[i]**2, left_sum+y[i]
            right_sumsq, right_sum = right_sumsq-y[i]**2, right_sum-y
            N_L, N_R = N_L+1, N_R-1
            if(N_L >= 1 and N_R >= 1):
                impurity = N_L/N*(left_sumsq/N_L - left_sum**2/N_L**2)\
                        + N_R/N*(right_sumsq/N_R - right_sum**2/N_R**2)
                if(impurity < best_imp):
                    best_imp = impurity
                    best_feat = feature_index
                    best_thresh = X_sort[i]
    return (np.var(Y)-best_imp, best_feat, best_thresh)
```

Note:

I am using the scikit learn terminology here with "impurity" as the variance and I returned the impurity decrease as in the formula: N_t / N * (impurity - N_t_R / N_t * right_impurity- N_t_L / N_t * left_impurity)

Having a duplicated feature value x (with different output y) in the dataset could still affect the calculation to the variance and I believe this would not be correct. So, I do not loop over the unique values of x.